# PayPal not Prepopulating All Form Fields

Tags: forms, paypal

I'm using the variables found on this page: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0J0VU

to try to pre-populate the form data for buyers when they purchase things on my site. The trouble is, some of the fields are getting filled in, while others are not. First name, last name, telephone number, and email address work without a problem.

However, the country is always set to the USA, and address1, address2, city, and zip are left blank.  I'm sure my code is correct.  I'm currently using the sandbox for testing. Has anyone else experienced this problem and can tell me what the solution is?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you pass over all the address fields.  If you do not pass over one of the variables, the address will not be displayed.  If this still does not work, can you provide an example of what you are sending over and list what is not getting displayed when you test this and I will look into it further.  However, make sure you are passing over all of the address fields.

Comment: Hey Chad - which address fields are required?  Do I pass over address2 even if the customer hasn't filled out an address2 line when they registered for my site?  Do I pass over state even if they are not from the US?  What's the best way to handle these circumstances?

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass over the address 2 field, but you would need to pass over a state.  It depends on the country but typically you would pass over the state, province, territory, or etc for the particular country.  If it's still not working can you provide your code and what you are trying to pass over.

Comment: Thanks Chad - I know I would use "state" to pass over state, but what variable should I use to pass over a province, region, or territory?

Comment: You would still use the state variable.  If its not working can you provide what you are sending.